# WPF, code behind can't update viewmodel code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Please spare my mistake. I am learning new things. So need your advice/help.
Any suggestion/help would be appriciated.

For some testing reason,

i am calling a method that inside ViewModel like this this -

```
ViewModel.VM_StockIn vM_StockIn = new ViewModel.VM_StockIn();
vM_StockIn.LoadDGStockIN();
```

and the method in viewmodel is like below

```
public void LoadDGStockIN()
{
    VendorName = "new name";
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VendorName));
}
```

but the problem is that i can't see any update in the UI whereas the same method if call from the default costructor of the viewmodel it works fine.

Comment: xaml was created a VM which binding to View. Your created a new object VM. Binding his to your View

Comment: yes, Thanks for commenting.

Comment: But how do i update on the that object created by view.

Comment: You can access it via `(ViewModel.VM_StockIn)DataContext`

Comment: Thank God. Thanks a lot. You have opened my eyes. My very big problem is solved now  for this trick.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new `ViewModel` object that knows nothing about your `View`.
You can create base class for all ViewModels and invoke `PropertyChanged` automatically

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    // Use this method for set property LOOK THIS (1)
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T store, T value, [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(store, value))
            return false;

        store = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(prop);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Using `SetProperty` method example

```
class YourViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   private string _vendorName;

   public string VendorName 
   {
       get => _vendorName; 
       
       // LOOK THIS ! (2)
       set => SetProperty(ref _vendorName, value);
   }

   public void LoadDGStockIN()
   {
      VendorName = "new name"; //VM property was updated
   }
}
```

*also, sorry for the bad English*

Comment: This idea not bad. Impressive one. Thanks a lot for answering.